# floor function and check if my answer is correct

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$ ⌊x^2⌋ =3  $$
$$⌊x^2⌋≤x^2<⌊x^2⌋+1 $$
$$ 3≤x^2<4 $$
$$ x^2<4 =  \sqrt{4}<x<\sqrt{4} $$
$$ 3≤x^2 $$
$$ x\le \:-\sqrt{3}\quad \mathrm{or}\quad \:x\ge \sqrt{3} $$

Comment: This looks a lot better than it did earlier today.  Still, you haven't quite gotten the punchline.  You had gotten to $3\leq x^2<4$ and then gone off with several unconnected lines which should have been connected.  Recall that $3\leq x^2<4$ means that *both* $3\leq x^2$ *and* that $x^2<4$ simultaneously.

Comment: As for the fourth line you wrote... that is a jumbled mess., but it looks like you *intended* to write that $x^2<4$ *is logically equivalent to* (*this should have been an $\iff$ or similar symbol, not an equals symbol*) $\color{red}{-}\sqrt{4}<x<\sqrt{4}$.  Now, it would have been helpful to simplify $\sqrt{4}$ as $2$.

Comment: So, you should have had simultaneously that $-2<x<2$ *and* $x\leq -\sqrt{3}$ or $x\geq \sqrt{3}$... which can be simplified as $x\in (-2,-\sqrt{3}]\cup [\sqrt{3},2)$

Answer (score 1):

It looks good, though i think you forgot a negative in you expansion of $x^2<4$,

as $x^2<4$  $⟺$  $-\sqrt{4}<x<\sqrt{4} $

which simplifies to $-2<x<2$.

so your solutions are all $x$ that satisfy that condition and the one on your last line, $ x\le \:-\sqrt{3}\quad \mathrm{or}\quad \:x\ge \sqrt{3}$

These conditions can be further tidied to, $-2<x≤-\sqrt{3}$  $ $ or $\sqrt{3}≤x<2$

but thats all notation, your solution looks to be correct

hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

After you obtain $$3 \le x^2<4$$

We have $$3 \le |x|^2 < 4$$

$$\sqrt3 \le |x| < 2$$

Hence the solution is $-2 < x \le -\sqrt3$ or $ \sqrt3 \le x < 2$.

Comment about your approach:

Seems to have typos and after you obtain $-2 < x < 2$ and $(x \le -\sqrt3) \lor (x \ge \sqrt3)$, you might like to sketch the corresponding region on the number line to help you identify the region.